# How to add Jenkins plugin (Recorder/Notifier/Publisher) to new project by default?

Tags: java, plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm developing a plugin which I need to run on every single project in my Jenkins cluster. I need a way to ensure it is added by default when new projects are created (I can use groovy to add it to the existing projects).

I know from developing another plugin in the past, with ListViewColumn there is a shownByDefault() in the descriptor. I can't seem to find an equivalent for Recorder/Notifier/Publisher... although I'm happy to use any other class providing I can have the logic run after a build and add a BadgeAction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by implementing [`hudson.model.listeners.ItemListener`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/listeners/ItemListener.html).

It has `onLoaded()`, `onCreated(Item item)`, `onUpdated(Item item)`, which can be used to add in this case a `Notifier` to the project... the Item can be casted to `AbstractProject`, then `getPublishersList().add(`*instance to add*`)`.

Don't forget when modifying the build or project objects in this way to call `.save()` to ensure your changes are persisited.

Comment: Thanks to @Slav for inspiration on this answer, via the source of [Template plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) which he linked to

Answer (score 2):

Will [Inheritance](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/inheritance-plugin) and [Template](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) plugins suffice?

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't really want to use the plugins as-is. However a quick glance at the source of Template plugin might be a good way to ensure my plugin is added (https://github.com/jenkinsci/template-project-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/templateproject/ItemListenerImpl.java).

I will explore later and report back...